# Polymorphism compile error

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use this polymorphism:

```
public class Player {


}

public class Warrior extends Player{

}
```

Now when I try to build new warrior object like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Player p = new Warrior();
    }
}
```

I get error from the compiler:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Warrior to Player

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for helping.

Comment: No the error is somewhere else or try to clean/build your project.

Comment: I assume, you are using an older or another class file, where Warrior doen't extend Player. If you are using an IDE like Exlipse, a clean and a fresh rebuild will help.

Comment: like @ZouZou said , there is no prob in the above code you have written , the problem is somewhere else

Comment: Otherwise check your imports to make sure that you always use the good Player class.

Comment: i had to clean and reopen eclipse. Eclipse is jsut buggy

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was caused by a bug. A clean and rebuild apparently solved it.